# How do you mitigate the Terrapin SSH attack?

Tags: ssh, security, encryption, openssh, vulnerability

The [Terrapin Attack on SSH](https://terrapin-attack.com/) details a *"prefix truncation attack targeting the SSH protocol. More precisely, Terrapin breaks the integrity of SSH's secure channel. By carefully adjusting the sequence numbers during the handshake, an attacker can remove an arbitrary amount of messages sent by the client or server at the beginning of the secure channel without the client or server noticing it."*

How would you change the SSH configuration to mitigate this attack?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This sounds like a big scarry attack, but it's an easy fix. To mitigate the attack, see my [Thwarting the Terrapin Attack](https://www.linuxglobal.com/thwarting-the-terrapin-ssh-attack/) article for SSH configuration details.  Specifically you need to block the ETM HMACs and ChaCha20 cipher as follows:

For recent RHEL-based Linux systems (Alma, Rocky Oracle, etc), this will work:

```bash
# cat /etc/crypto-policies/policies/modules/TERRAPIN.pmod
cipher@ssh = -CHACHA20*
ssh_etm = 0

# update-crypto-policies --set DEFAULT:TERRAPIN
Setting system policy to DEFAULT:TERRAPIN
Note: System-wide crypto policies are applied on application start-up.
It is recommended to restart the system for the change of policies
to fully take place.
```

Alternatively, you can force AES-GCM which is [not vulnerable](https://terrapin-attack.com/#question-answer) if your system doesn't have (or doesn't use) `update-crypto-policies` (eg,  as noted by @StephenKitt, Debian/Ubuntu may not use crypto-policies by default):

```
# cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config
[...]
Ciphers aes256-gcm@openssh.com
```

Then test with [the testing tool](https://github.com/RUB-NDS/Terrapin-Scanner/releases/tag/v1.1.0) provided by the original researchers.

Comment: Note that Debian (and Ubuntu, as far as I know) *doesn’t* use `crypto-policies` by default.

Comment: @StephenKitt, I believe that is correct too.  However, I _have_ seen Ubuntu deployments on AWS with `update-crypto-policies` installed in a semi-default deployment from an AWS-provided AMI, but not sure if they were actually being used or if it was simply available for use.

Answer (score 0):

Also suggest to use

data-ciphers AES-256-GCM

on openvpn server conf as it may seem irrevelant(as terrapin related to sshd protocol) but better protection